# split() not working with mySQL join?

Tags: mysql, common-schema

I'm currently using the mySQL common schema package along with the `split()` function, but I'm struggling to get a working `JOIN` query to work?

```
set @script := "
    split({size:2000} :
        UPDATE world
        SET world.CountryName = (
            SELECT country.nicename 
            FROM country
            WHERE country.iso = world.Country
        )
    )
    {
        throttle 4;
        SELECT $split_total_rowcount AS 'rows updated so far';
    }
";
call common_schema.run(@script);
```

When running this query, it produces the following:

```
#1644 - QueryScript error: [split() cannot deduce split table name. Please specify explicitly] at 34: "UPDATE world
```

SET world.Country

As for why I'm trying to split my `UPDATE` query into chunks, is because it's trying to update a table that's got 3M+ rows & is struggling when doing the query on it's own

Comment: I don't know your framework at all, but you can always check running the raw update query directly on MySQL.  Obviously, if that has a problem then so would your code.

Comment: I have never used split. But, do you think it wants you to reference your database in your table call?

Answer (score 0):

`Please specify explicitly` appears to refer to using this format:

> Multiple tables operations; explicit declaration of splitting table:
>
> `split (schema_name.table_name: statement operating on multiple tables)`
>
> `statement;`

https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/query_script_split.html

See also [explicit declaration](https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/query_script_split.html#explicit).